# Printing a 2D array

Tags: c, matrix, printf, transpose

When I call this function in main() and pass a transpose matrix as a parameter, it throws wrong values.

```
void mostrarMatriz(int matriz[filas][columnas], int filas, int columnas){
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < filas; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < columnas; j++){
            printf("[%d]", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should show what is your input, the output and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced i,j in the printing function

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define filas 3
#define columnas 3

void mostrarMatriz(int matriz[filas][columnas]){
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < filas; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < columnas; j++){
            printf("[%d]", matriz[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int matrix[filas][columns];
    int i,j;
    int num=1;
    for(i=0;i<filas;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<columnas;j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j]=num;
            num=num+1;
        }
    }
    mostrarMatriz(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

This works fine —
you can check it here:
https://onlinegdb.com/HkHcNqOVv

Output:

```
[1][4][7]
[2][5][8]
[3][6][9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that your function definition should not compile:

```c
void mostrarMatriz(int matriz[filas][columnas], int filas, int columnas){
    …
}
```

Unless there are global variables `filas` and `columnas` visible, you should get warnings similar to:

```
tp61.c:6:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'filas'
void mostrarMatriz(int matriz[filas][columnas], int filas, int columnas){
                              ^
tp61.c:6:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'columnas'
void mostrarMatriz(int matriz[filas][columnas], int filas, int columnas){
```

You need to define the variables before the matrix in the function definition.

```c
void mostrarMatriz(int filas, int columns, int matriz[filas][columnas]){
```

With that fixed, your code prints a matrix without transposing it.  It is easy to adapt the code to print the transpose of the matrix.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

static void mostrarMatriz(int filas, int columnas, int matriz[filas][columnas])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
        {
            printf("[%d]", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

static void printTransposeMatrix(int filas, int columnas, int matriz[filas][columnas])
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
        {
            printf("[%d]", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    /* Created by: gen_matrix -E -H 99 -L 10 -c 6 -r 4 -i */
    /* Random seed: 0xE8327715 */
    int matrix[4][6] =
    {
        { 42, 44, 15, 32, 32, 12, },
        { 89, 90, 74, 43, 20, 49, },
        { 49, 47, 39, 96, 70, 72, },
        { 74, 96, 75, 85, 59, 37, },
    };
    enum { MATRIX_ROWS = 4, MATRIX_COLS = 6 };

    mostrarMatriz(MATRIX_ROWS, MATRIX_COLS, matrix);
    printTransposeMatrix(MATRIX_ROWS, MATRIX_COLS, matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
[42][44][15][32][32][12]
[89][90][74][43][20][49]
[49][47][39][96][70][72]
[74][96][75][85][59][37]
[42][89][49][74]
[44][90][47][96]
[15][74][39][75]
[32][43][96][85]
[32][20][70][59]
[12][49][72][37]
```